# Can't connect tableViewController to Outlet?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view controller in my storyboard, which I'm trying to create an outlet of. I have setup the custom class of the tableView but when I ctrl drag to the code using the assistant editor I'm getting no feedback?

Here's a picture showing the view with the correct custom class and the assistant editor code.

[image: picture]

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give same class name in both the view controller and Xib (GFGroupsViewController)
but in above picture both are different (GroupsViewController and GFGroupsViewController) once check it.

Comment: But in the picture you can see I am assigning the custom class of the xib to GFGroupsViewController and the class name in the view controller is also GFGroupsViewController. Where is it setting just GroupsViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assign a Wrong class to the viewController

check this.

[image]
[image]

You are connected with storyBoard is GroupViewController and try co connect IBOutletwith CFGroupViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you suggestions guys. This is really weird I didn't change anything, I just reloaded the files and tried again and this time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should make sure that you have assigned the correct class to your table view controller, if you are still not able to connect the outlet then try and restart XCode.